# Enabling both UART ports in GPIO

Tags: gpio, pi-3, rpi.gpio, uart

I have a project at this moment, and I had to disable the **Bluetooth** of my Raspberry Pi 3 to use the `AMA0` port, I mean the main **UART** port. At this moment I need use both ports: `AMA0` and `ttyS0`. Are there some form to put the `ttyS0` on the **GPIO** again, using both **UARTs** at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a compute module you are limited to a single UART.

On some Pi's (not the Pi3) you can choose to use /dev/ttyAMA0 or /dev/ttyS0 but only ONE at a time as they use the same GPIO.